# why my elasticsearch has some problem, can't search some thing?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

My elasticsearch query is

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "currency.keyword": "*oke*"
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "search_tags.keyword": "*BTC*USDT"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "record_type.keyword": "market"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "currency.keyword": "*BTC*"
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "search_tags.keyword": "*oke*USDT"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "record_type.keyword": "market"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "currency.keyword": "*USDT*"
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "search_tags.keyword": "*oke*BTC"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "record_type.keyword": "market"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
}
```

It return null from my index.

But when my query is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "search_tags.keyword": "okexBTC*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "currency.keyword": "USD"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "record_type.keyword": "market"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

it return something.

Comment: Can we have any sample documents from your index so that debugging is easier?

Comment: Hi @Eqer, have you checked my answer? would you please check whether the queries in your examples are correct?

Answer (score 0):

If the queries in your example are correct, it is legit that the second query might have hits whilst the first query has none. This is because the condition in the second query doesn't match any of the `should` cases of the first query. Just look at the `"currency.keyword": "USD"` condition of the second query: this condition is impossible to match in the first query.